# Send token on static URL adonisJS

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

How would you send token on static url on adonisJS?

All request send token but this request on static URL donit received token

code on module
[image]

[error get on access static URL http://127.0.0.1:3333/contracts/1/files/1 but don have a JWT token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elqV3.png)

Comment: when are you sending the token?

Comment: Can you add more details to your question? thx :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont send token, I want send but I dont know.

I want send token on computed properties ['url'].

Comment: okay, you want to send token on http request (like : `.../contracts?token=<token>`). Is that right?